# GAE Datastore - cannot start LocalDevelopmentDatastore programmatically on Windows

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-api-java-client

**Environment:**
Java API `google-api-services-datastore-protobuf v1beta2-rev1-3.0.0`.
OS: Windows 7.

**Goal:**
Start Local Datastore Server using the method:

```
public void start(String sdkPath, String dataset, String cmdLineOptions)
```

from `com.google.api.services.datastore.client.LocalDevelopmentDatastore.java` in order to use it in unit tests.

**Steps:**
I downloaded gcd tool `gcd-v1beta2-rev1-3.0.2.zip` and put it to `C:\gcd` folder
(paths to `gcd.cmd` and `gcd.sh` are `C:\gcd).
Also, I set environment variables:

```
"DATASTORE_HOST"="http://localhost:8080" and  
"DATASTORE_DATASET"="myapp".
```

**Problem:**

> LocalDevelopmentDatastoreException occurs.
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "./gcd.sh" (in directory "C:\gcd"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified.

Note that it tries to find `./gcd.sh` but not `gcd.cmd`.

**Java code:**

```
String datasetName = "myapp";
String hostName = "http://localhost:8080";

DatastoreOptions options = new DatastoreOptions.Builder()
            .host(hostName)
            .dataset(datasetName).build();

LocalDevelopmentDatastoreOptions localOptions = new LocalDevelopmentDatastoreOptions.Builder()
            .addEnvVar("DATASTORE_HOST", hostName)
            .addEnvVar("DATASTORE_DATASET", datasetName).build();

LocalDevelopmentDatastore datastore = LocalDevelopmentDatastoreFactory.get().create(options, localOptions);

datastore.start("C:\\gcd", datasetName);
```

This code is based on the example from LocalDevelopmentDatastore.java documentation.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though the method is only programmed to look for `gcd.sh`, as it doesn't appear there's anything in your config which could have helped this to not fail. I suggest you open a defect report in the [Cloud Platform Public Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-cloud-platform/issues/list).

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider [gcloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/) for using the Datastore?
It also has an option for programmatically starting the local datastore using [LocalGcdHelper](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java/blob/master/gcloud-java-datastore/src/test/java/com/google/gcloud/datastore/LocalGcdHelper.java) which should work on Windows.